# Google Script: Email automisation: No bugs, but code still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first attempt with Google Script, hence why it is very basic. Goal is to make the script go through all lines of my database and send emails out if a specific cell is not empty (to prevent sending out the email multiple times). Then the script is supposed to write into the cell to mark it as sent.

I know there are addons for this, but the ones that I tried caused the connection between google sheets and the database I was using, and that was feeding into this, to break, which is why I am writing my own piece of script.

The Google Sheets document I am using has two sheets: 1) "Sheet 1", that holds a specific complaint information, and 2) "Sheet 2", that tells us who to send it to.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

Below is my script, I know this is very basic, but this is the level of comprehension I have now:

```
function automate_mail() {

  //defines a counter for lines

  var counter = 0;



  // repeats for all lines

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];



 // Checks if cell is empty, if yes then do sth

  var check_field_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(5,2 + counter); 
  var check_field = check_field.getValue();
    if (check_field!==""){



  // severity level

  var complaint_level_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,2 + counter); 
  var complaint_level = complaint_level_range.getValue();



  // message1

  var message1_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(3,2 + counter); 
  var message1 = message1_range.getValue();



  // message2

  var message2_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(4,2+counter); 
  var message2 = message2_range.getValue();



  // message3

  var message3_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(5,2+counter); 
  var message3 = message3_range.getValue();



  // message4

  var message4_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(6,2+counter); 
  var message4 = message4_range.getValue(); 



  // complaint_message

  var complaint_message_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(3,2 + counter); 
  var complaint_message = complaint_message_range.getValue(); 



  // location

  var location_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,2 + counter); 
  var location = location_range.getValue();



  //gets email address

   var email_address_range = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetbyName("Sheet2").getRange(1,2 + counter);
   var email_address = email_address_range.value();



   //gets name

   var name_range = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetbyName("Sheet2").getRange(2,2 + counter);
   var name = name_range.value();



   //gets date

   var date_range = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetbyName("Sheet1").getRange(1,2 + counter);
   var date = date_range.value();



  // This parses the data for the email to send

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, "New complaint"+date , message1+complaint_level+message2+location+message3+complaint_message+message4);



 //fill in control box

 ActiveSheet("Sheet1");
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5,2 + counter).setValue("1");



 // increase counter by 1

 counter = counter + 1 



//else do nothing

 //else{}

}
}
}
```

Comment: What’s the linkage between the two shades?

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  for (i in data) {
...
```

You define data as the the sheet, this not possible, you need to retrieve

1. the range of interest with [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) or [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
2. the data in thsi range with [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
3. Keep in minf that the data you retrieve will be a 2-D value array, so still you can not iterate with one `for loop` through all data, but you need to iterate either through rows or columns (or, in case you need to iterate through both - you need two nested for loops)

Second Issue:

`var check_field_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(5,2 + counter);`

In you image the fields under `Check` are empty. Thus, the condition
`if (check_field!=="")` (non empty check field) is not fulfilled an consequently, the rest of the code including sending the email will not be fulfilled.

You need to retrieve your data conrrectly and rethink the logic of your for loop.

A good help to debug is to introduce into your code logs - like `Logger.log("log somethink")` at strategic positions like e.g. before and after entering a `for` loop or and `if` statement. This will help you to udnerstand until where your code executes.